# Why does adding a sleep to this function break it?

Tags: python, pygame, sleep, maze

I have a function (called generateMaze) that is supposed to generate a maze but so far I just have it find every 'cell' in a grid. When it find the cell it marks the cell as 'visited'. I mark each cell with a black circle but when it has been 'visited' it should be marked as green. When I run the program everything turns green instantly. I would like to add a sleep at the end of the generateMaze function so I can see the process of the cells turning green happen instead of it happening instantly. In the function it prints "Len: {len(openCells)}" Which prints the amount of cells it is allowed to go to. If I add a sleep anywhere in the function, it will start printing out numbers that go way over the possible max which is 4.

```py
# Function
def generateMaze(x=40, y=40): 
    global cells
    possiblePositions = []
    openCells = []

    # These are all the possible positions that we can go to
    possiblePositions.append([x-80, y])
    possiblePositions.append([x+80, y])
    possiblePositions.append([x, y-80])
    possiblePositions.append([x, y+80])

    # Find open cells using the possiblePositions
    for cell in cells:
        for i in range(len(possiblePositions)):
            if cell.x == possiblePositions[i][0] and cell.y == possiblePositions[i][1] and (not cell.visited()):
                openCells.append(cell)

    # Choose random cell
    print("Len: ", len(openCells))
    if len(openCells) > 0:
        targetCell = openCells[randint(0, len(openCells)-1)]
        if targetCell in cells:
            cells[cells.index(targetCell)].visit()
        else:
            print("Error: Could not find targetCell in cells")
        generateMaze(targetCell.x, targetCell.y)
    else:
        print("Done generating")
```

```py
#mainloop
while not done:
    # [...]    

    if shouldGenMaze:
        shouldGenMaze = False
        print("Generating Maze...")
        x = threading.Thread(target = generateMaze)
        x.start()

    # [...]
```

Comment: Pleas edit your code to be a [mre]. Also indicate where you are trying to add sleep, and what actually happens with the sleep that “breaks” it - and say what is broken

Comment: Is there a global named `openCells` somewhere ?

Comment: @Kingsley No it is not

Comment: @Kingsley cells is a list that holds all the Cell objects. The Cell class has 3 variables x, y, and _visited. The x and y are the position of the cell and the visited is a false by default bool value that is changed when the classes function visit() is called. Also each cell is 40px away from eachother in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me.  Maybe it's something to do with your threading, hard to say with only the single function.

Obviously if you put the delay at the end of the function, you just get one big delay of recursion-tails.

Here's my MRE:

```
import random
import time

cells = []

class Cell:
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.been_there = False

    def visited( self ):
        return self.been_there
    def visit( self ):
        self.been_there = True


def generateMaze(x=40, y=40):
    global cells
    possiblePositions = []
    openCells = []

    # These are all the possible positions that we can go to
    possiblePositions.append([x-80, y])
    possiblePositions.append([x+80, y])
    possiblePositions.append([x, y-80])
    possiblePositions.append([x, y+80])

    # Find open cells using the possiblePositions
    for cell in cells:
        for i in range(len(possiblePositions)):
            if cell.x == possiblePositions[i][0] and cell.y == possiblePositions[i][1] and (not cell.visited()):
                openCells.append(cell)

    # Choose random cell
    print("Len: ", len(openCells))
    if len(openCells) > 0:
        targetCell = openCells[random.randint(0, len(openCells)-1)]
        if targetCell in cells:
            cells[cells.index(targetCell)].visit()
        else:
            print("Error: Could not find targetCell in cells")
        time.sleep( 1 )
        generateMaze(targetCell.x, targetCell.y)
    else:
        print("Done generating")



SIZE=121  #?
for y in range( 0, SIZE ):
    for x in range( 0, SIZE ):
        cells.append( Cell( x, y ) )

generateMaze()
```